# /app/app/models/translation.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class Translation (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i followed this [article](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/05/31/beyond-yml-files-dynamic-translations) to implement translations through a admin page

This works great in my localhost, but when i push to heroku this message appears:

"/app/app/models/translation.rb:1:in `': superclass mismatch for class Translation (TypeError)"

My MODEL TRanslation:

```
class Translation < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Can anyone help me, i don't have any idea to solve this

Answer (score 2):

Maybe **Translation** is already `key` class on heroku. If so, you have to rename that model.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the model, routes, controller, helpers and views to "Language", but keeping the table name as "translations". Then i put table_name = 'translations' in Language Model:

app/model/language.rb

```
class Language < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "translations"
end
```